# Youtube Live stream with reactjs

Tags: reactjs, youtube, live-streaming

I am streaming live videos on youtube and I want to add the stream to my reactjs website. 
I want users to sign in and then go to a page where the video is playing through a player.

How is that possible? Can I just copy the url and use react-youtube to do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

For anyone looking for the answer to this question. The simplest solution is with youtube-react and you paste the stream ID. Works just fine but you cannot disable the share option so if you want some privacy this is not the best option. Since I wanted to stream a skype video I used skype with OBS to stream it to youtube. It is dead simple.